# Python - Altair - Stacked Bar Chart With Selection

Tags: python, data-visualization, stacked-area-chart, altair

I've followed and replicated with my dataset two tutorials, linked below

```
Stacked Bar Chart : https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html
```

and

```
Selectable Data : https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interactive_cross_highlight.html
```

I'm having difficulty understanding if Altair is capable of combining these two, though.

Is it possible to have a stacked bar graph, where each "subsection" of the graph is selectable.  So, something like if I had data that was like

```
Category1, Category2
```

in bars, and each one can have subsections

```
Sub1, Sub2
```

I'd have a stacked bar graph where say the Categroy1/Category2 parts that are related to Sub1 are Blue, the parts related to Sub2 are Orange, and I can select any of the 4 parts (Cat1+Sub1, Cat1+Sub2, Cat2+Sub1, Cat2+Sub2, represented as 2 stacked bars) and that part then turns Red.

Is this possible or out-of-scope, and if possible, what am I missing conceptually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can specify in the selector which encodings you would like it to respond to; to respond to individual sections of the stacked bar, specify `x` and `color`.

Here's an example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

selector = alt.selection_single(encodings=['x', 'color'])

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='variety',
    y='sum(yield)',
    color=alt.condition(selector, 'site', alt.value('lightgray'))
).add_selection(
    selector
)
```

[image]

[click here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgVwE4BsVTkQHoAjWXAUwE8A6AKwGcB7AO0gF8AacKAW3IDW+SGSyRuESBRYBjJtACWLAOb5QESXJxMxqdRs2tF8BazU8Dk+FQAOFYSya8lsPBMuSAZgoo5owhgV4e3cPSAZfChkTM1RwyOidSAsNLhTJADdXDHs4nAVlAAt4ZSxYKmSDNINIAA81SGs7BycXNyhvX384rKwfaw5QqAq9RttcqABHDFgWE0QTDJCoWGVSimUECfCMXnEOnz9hKkP-dh5qqAicKJi2PRT4m8TdNHSoJu3AlRvxd6lZPIlMoGPgANp1faQLRJAC6Q0ksSgMnyMiECKgWAozBwS2Eym0ZDc-wovBsAzirjwKXOEHO7CAA) to try it live in the vega editor.

Comment: Exciting! Can't try it myself until tonight, but this is EXACTLY what I was hoping could work. Now to tie this into the circle heatgraphs and have some really fun visualizations. Appreciate your help!!!